# Using JavaCV with Maven

Tags: maven, java-native-interface, maven-3, javacv

I'm trying to use JavaCV/OpenCV with maven. It seems I've got the pom.xml file right, simply adding:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
  <version>0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

However, it seems to not find the DLL-files it requires giving me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_objdetect in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:524)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:399)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.<clinit>(opencv_objdetect.java:14)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:374)
    at com.seria.JavaVideo.main(JavaVideo.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_objdetect249 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:524)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:390)
    ... 11 more
```

How to go about it? Maven and JavaCV are both new to me.